# How to login as a user in a course registration system in Java

Tags: java, session, authentication, servlets

I am in the middle of creating a very basic course registration form on Netbeans using a web project. I have managed to get it to the point where a student can register by filling out a registration form. The entered information is then saved into a Derby DB. Now I need it to allow the registered student to log in in order to search for classes to add/drop.

Here is my code for the RegServlet.java file that takes the user input and stores them in a DB:

```
public class RegServlet extends HttpServlet {
SaveToDB toDB = new SaveToDB();

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        try {
            doStuff(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException {
    //see if search parameter is present        
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String passWord = request.getParameter("passWord");                
    if(!userName.isEmpty()&&!passWord.isEmpty()&&!lastName.isEmpty()&&!firstName.isEmpty()&&!age.isEmpty()&& (sex=='F' || sex=='M') &&!email.isEmpty()) {
        request.setAttribute("userName", userName);
        request.setAttribute("passWord", passWord);

        toDB.createConnection();
        toDB.insertNewUser(userName, passWord, lastName, firstName, age, sex, email);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);            
    } else {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }            
}
```

And here is my newUser.jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>New User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="RegServlet">
        <h1>Register!</h1>
            Fill out information below:<p>                

            Username:
            <input type="text" name="userName" value =""><p>
            Password:
            <input type="text" name="passWord" value =""><p>                

            <input type="submit" value="Finish!"><p>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var var1 = "<%= (String) request.getAttribute("userName")%>";
                    if(var1 == (""))
                        document.write("<bSystem doesn't like an empty string.....Try Again!!!</b>");    

                    var var2 = "<%= (String) request.getAttribute("passWord")%>";
                    if(var2 == (""))
                        document.write("<bSystem doesn't like an empty string.....Try Again!!!</b>");
                </script>


    </form>
</body>
```

This jsp code piece `<form method="get" action="RegServlet">` links my code to the RegServlet.java file and in the RegServlet class, I used `RequestDispatcher` to send the user to the next page named login.jsp to actually log in.

I need some help with the login.jsp file. Here is my login.jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="Login" action="RegServlet">
    <h1>Login!</h1>        
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="userName" value =""><p>
    Password:
    <input type="text" name="passWord" value =""><p>

    <input type="submit" value="Login!"><p>
</body>
```

I have another method named `doLogin()` in my RegServlet.java class file under `doStuff()` where I will match the username with the password that is stored in the DB. And if the username and password match, I want to start a session for the student that wishes to log in to the system to search for classes that will also be stored in the DB.

How should I go about the method `doLogin()`? Where should I implement this method? Under the `doStuff()` method? Or another class? And how should I start the authentication process?

I am just practicing the basics first before I deal with all the security and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, you should not be checking the username and password in Javascript like you are doing now in newUser.jsp  You should do that on the server side. That text "System doesn't like an empty string" should be coming from a call to a class.  When you print out the password into javascript like you are doing, it becomes visible to the user if they view source. Not very secure if someone intercepts the traffic.

Also, once you validate the username/password in your servlet, you should do a response.sendRedirect rather than forward.  Forward will forward all the parameters on to the next page.  You don't need to keep forwarding the password to every page.  If the userid/password was right, set a session variable, sendRedirect to the index page, and on the index page pull the session variable and check if the guy is logged in, and if not, redirect back to the login page.

Now, DO NOT set the password in a session variable.  That's bad.  Just set the username in a session variable.  Be more careful with passwords.  And only set the username in the session variable if the username/password was right.  Then on the index page you can grab the username from the session, and if the username in the session is not null or blank, you know the guy is logged in.  Otherwise, if username in session is null or empty string, you know the guy is not logged in, so redirect to login page.

And as for where to put your doLogin vs doStuff, the login servlet really only needs to validate the login, so why not just rename doStuff to doLogin and put all of the code in there?

One more thing: For logins you should use POST not GET, so in your servlet change doGet to doPost, and in your login.jsp make the method=POST in your form tag.  You don't want users passwords visible in the address bar (which is what get does).  (There is not such thing as method=login in a form tag; its method=post)

Also, for your password text box, use type="password" Not type="text". The difference is, that type='password' will obscure the password as it is typed.

Comment: Thank you, junk. This was very helpful. So in my newUser.jsp, `<form method="get" action="RegServlet">` should be changed to `<form method="POST" action="RegServlet">`? And how do I create a session variable?